# Cannot create a second account on my private chain from the Ethereum Wallet

Tags: private-blockchain

Just playing around with Ethereum. I create my very first private-chain on a Windows machine..

First I'm starting up the node/miner:

> D:\ethereum\gethlatest>geth --dev --rpc --rpcport 8002  --datadir
>   D:\ethereum\gethlatest\privatechain --ipcpath
>   D:\ethereum\gethlatest\privatechain console

This is running without an issue. Then I am going to create the first address which I will use to collect the Ethers that the miner will mine:

```
personal.newAccount('myPassword')
```

Then, I will start the miner:

```
miner.start()
```

It starts mining, with every block the miner mines, 5 Ether is being credited to the address I just created. No problems here.

Now, I am going to start the wallet client:

```
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\EthereumWallet\app-0.8.7>"Ethereum Wallet.exe" --rpc http://localhost:8002
```

Ethereum wallet is looking for peers, can't seem to find one. I'm clicking Launch   When the wallet opens, I see the first address created with some Ethers in it. Good!

However, in the client terminal the first error appears:

> [2016-10-28 09:50:53.617] [WARN] (ui: wallet) - %cUnhandled rejection
>   UnknownError: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
>   color: red

Meanwhile in the client:
I want to create another address/account. I want to send some ETH to it, just to play around. I choose "add account" and enter a password and the again for confirmation.

This doesn't work, in the client terminal:

> 2016-10-28 09:55:38.648] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request
>   failed { code: -32601,   message: 'The method personal_newAccount does
>   not exist/is not available' }

Any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: try to run geth without rpcport and ipcpath